# No Virtual Device(flutter project)

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

I'm trying to run my new flutter project in Android Studio. I want to run it on an emulator. I created the new virtual device but Android Studio doesn't see this device.

Virtual Device -:
[image]

Android Studio -:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment, so I am writing it as an answer.

Click the [run button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m31Ju.png) on the action column of the virtual device list.

Comment: it doesn't work.when i hit the button it says no connected device.

Comment: I mean the button on the virtual device list, not android studio. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m31Ju.png)

Comment: Tried. it's not the problem.

Comment: What kind of error did you get? Can you try flutter doctor and see if there is any error.

Comment: I found the answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your emulator did not added correctly, try again